# Class project auto-grader says "standard output is not what was expected"

Tags: java

I am new to java and am doing a project for my class but I keep getting an error.

> ### Project
>
> Write an application that reads values  representing a time duration in hours, minutes, and seconds and then prints the equivalent total number of seconds. (For example, 1 hour, 28 minutes, and 42 seconds is equivalent to 5322 seconds.)
>
> **SPECIFICATION OF PROMPTS, LABELS AND OUTPUT:** Your code should use these prompts: "hours: ", "minutes: ", "seconds: ". The prompts should not force the user to type  the required input on the next line. After all the inputs, the output  should consist of a single line consisting of an integer  (the total number of seconds) followed by a space followed by a label for the units: seconds. For example:
>
> ```
> hours: 2
> minutes: 10
> seconds: 7
> 7807 seconds
> ```
>
> **SPECIFICATION OF NAMES:** Your application class should be called Seconds

**These are the errors MyProgrammingLab keeps giving me:**

[image: pic]

[image: pic2]

**My Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Seconds {
    
    public static void main (String[] args){
        
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int hours;
        System.out.print("hours: ");
        hours = stdin.nextInt();
        int minutes;
        System.out.print("minutes: ");
        minutes = stdin.nextInt();
        int seconds;
        System.out.print("seconds: ");
        seconds = stdin.nextInt();
        int hourSeconds = (hours * 60) * 60;
        int minuteSeconds = (minutes * 60);
        int secondsTotal = hourSeconds + minuteSeconds + seconds;
        System.out.println(secondsTotal + " seconds");
    
    }
                            }
```

Comment: You are missing a space in the last line of output. Try secondsTotal + " seconds".

Comment: Can you include the output of your code? ie. What the `System.out.println` statements output.

Comment: Hey thanks that actually helped a little. It fixed a part of it. I am still getting this though: http://i.imgur.com/2QPbvct.png

Comment: @grizzlyyy if it is some sort of tests, it is up to your enviroment that you are running it cuz your logic seems fine and your code runs perfectly

Comment: Heh yeah I ran it in Eclipse and it seems fine. MyProgrammingLab won't accept it though. It keeps giving me that error I showed in the screenshot. It also says "We think you might want to consider using: , (comma)". But I don't understand where the comma would go. I am still pretty new as this is my 3rd week of Java Class.

Comment: The problem specifically says not to require the user to type on the next line, but `println` adds a newline.

Comment: Ah, additionally the output is supposed to be *prompts*. Instead, you're performing the input without prompting and then printing out the contents of each variable. Did you actually try running the program and comparing the experience to the spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint, try:

```
...
System.out.print("hours: ");
int hours = stdin.nextInt();
...
```

Check the difference between `print` and `println`

Also note that you ONLY need to print the prompt, so you just need to print: "hours :".

Do the same for minutes and seconds.

Comment: Ahh it worked!!! Thank you. Added the space before the quotation and changed println to print and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @grizzlyyy Excelent!. If you find my answer helpful, please dont forget to accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your program silently expects the user to type 3 numbers, with no prompting for what they're entering. Then it prints back what they typed.

What you're supposed to do is print out an `"hours: "` prompt, then read in a number. Once you've got it, print the `"minutes: "` prompt, and wait again. Follow that with the `"seconds: "` prompt. Once you've got all three numbers, only *then* should you perform the computations and print the final line.

If it helps, here's the program's output again with the user's key strokes called out explicitly.

```
hours: 2Enter
minutes: 10Enter
seconds: 7Enter
7807 seconds
```

Notice how the expected output does *not* include the numbers that were entered. Do not print the numbers back out!

Comment: Ahh thank you. The order of my coding was off. I updated it and with JosEdu's suggestion it worked! Thanks to both of you!